# Identifying Behavior of Matrix Variable Assignment

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm trying to develop my own custom 'Matrix' class for use in pattern recognition and neural networks in C++. For the most part, it's working fine, but I'm running into an issue with my code when assigning variables. One method of assigning a variable is not working, and it seems to crash my code.

To give a little background, my matrix is an array of array of doubles within a class called Matrix. I've added appropriate constructors and destructors as well as a way to manipulate individual elements of a matrix. My main issue is assigning class variables. Say I have two matrices: A and B. The goal is to copy the contents from A to B. If I try one way, my code works as intended. If I try another way, my code crashes when trying to free after executing.

```
class Matrix{
    public:
        //Constructors
        Matrix();                   //EMPTY Matrix
        Matrix(int, int);           //Matrix WITH ROW AND COL
        ~Matrix();                  //Destructor

        void operator= (const Matrix &);

        double & operator() (int X,int Y) const{return this->array[X][Y]; }
        void print() const;                       //Print the Matrix
    private:
        double **array; 
        int nrows;
        int ncols;
        int ncell;
};


//When you want to copy a matrix to another Matrix variable
void Matrix::operator= (const Matrix &M) {

    if(this->array != NULL){
        for(int i=nrows-1; i>=0; i--)   free(this->array[i]);
        free(this->array);
        this->array = NULL;
    }

    //Using parameters from the matrix being copied, rebuild it
    this->nrows = M.nrows;  this->ncols = M.ncols;  this->ncell = M.ncell;

    //First, create an ariray of double* for the rows
    this->array = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*(this->nrows));

    //Next, go through each 'row', and copy over elements
    for(int i=0; i<(this->nrows); i++){
        this->array[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*(this->ncols));
        for(int j=0; j<(this->ncols); j++){
            this->array[i][j] = M.array[i][j];
        }
    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ //C.applyFunc(SP);

    printf("\n\nCreating  Matrix A\n");
    Matrix A(1,3);      A(0,0) = 8;

    printf("\n\nPRINTING \n\n");    A.print();

    printf("\n\nCreating B\n\n");

    Matrix B = A; //THIS IS THE PROBLEM RIGHT HERE!!!

    //Matrix B;
    //B = A;

    printf("\n\nPRINTING B\n\n");   B.print(); B(0,0) = 123;
    printf("PRINTING A AGAIN\n\n"); A.print();
    printf("PRINTING B AGAIN\n\n"); B.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In my code, I've posted my class, the operator overloading of '=', and my main function. The other functions aren't as important, just printing the matrix and what not. If you find it helpful, I'll include it later. Here, in my main code, matrix A is being assigned as a 1x3 row matrix, setting A[0][0] to 8. Printing out the matrix verifies this. Now, when I assign B to A as shown in the line that's not commented out, I expect B and A to have the same values. Later, I change B[0][0] to 123.

At the end of it all, I expect A to be [8, 0, 0] and B to be [123, 0, 0]. However, when I print out A and B again, they are both the same, [8, 0, 0]. It seems that somehow, B points to A, so when A is freed after B, it's already freed and it crashes. However, when I run the commented code and assign B that way, my code works exactly as I expect it to. What exactly is happening when I call 'Matrix B = A' that makes it different than the commented code below it?

Comment: You defined the copy assignment operator but not the copy ctor. What you think is assignment might be optimize as copy construction by a smart compiler.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts It is in fact required to be "optimized" in newer C++ standards. As in, `Matrix B = A;` is not an assignment but a (copy) initialization and thus directly calls `Matrix(const Matrix&)`.

Comment: While your code may be fine for educational purposes, there is no reason to 1. use  `malloc` and `free` in C++; 2. allocate for each matrix row (one allocation of size `cols*rows` will do better); 3. do manual memory management at all (`std::vector` does everything you need here) and 4. prefix every member access with `this->`. All of these things are frowned upon or worse.

Comment: @MaxLanghof thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks for your reply. I guess I did it this way because I was practicing a bit with C before, so I just got used to this style of memory management.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Thanks for your reply. I remember learning about copy contructors, but it's one of those things that I forgot about until the error comes. Thanks. I'll be sure to implement that in my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  in short,

```
Matrix B = A;
```

is not about executing assignment, but copy constructor, which, if I didnt miss something, is not defined in your class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see what you mean now. I vaguely remember the copy constructor, but it's been a while that I forgot how to use it, or actually remember to implement it. Thanks. I'll do some research on that then.

Comment: @user101402 you are welcome.